# Why is Conway notation relevant, instead of braid notation (for knots)

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants, braid-groups

In the early XXth century, Alexander showed that every knot is the closure of a braid, and Markov gave necessary and sufficient conditions for two braids to have the same closure.

My question is: why don't we represent knots by its braid word then? Why was Conway notation so celebrated? (It is often said that it is the first notation for knots that was i) systematic and ii) lets one deduce properties of the knot at first glance. But this is also true for the braid words, isn't it?)

I think I'm maybe not understanding what the hidden problem behind using braids as a notation system is. For instance, there's a 2004 paper by Gittings on using braids as a knotational system — why did we have to wait since Markov's Theorem to 2004 to get this knotational system?

I only recently started reading into knot theory, so I might be being naive.

Comment: I find it harder to deduce properties of a knot "at a glance" from braid notation than from traditional knot notation... but that's just me.

Comment: Although [Alexander's Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Alexander%27s_theorem) provides an algorithm to represent any link as a braid closure, it often feels "inefficient" in the sense that a relatively simple link can have a minimal braid that's quite complicated. This is a direct consequence of the condition that ensures a tangle is a braid (can't turn around). Conway's tangle notation is more flexible, hence more amenable to all the possible configurations that can arise in a link projection.

Comment: There are many other ways to represent a link, and there's a sort of conservation law at work. If your method is more rigid and/or is build from a more limited set of components, then the representations of particular links tend to be more complicated (e.g. [grid diagrams](https://picturethismaths.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/grid-diagrams-for-knots) used in combinatorial link Floer homology). This is reminiscent of the tension in place-value number systems between having more possible digits but shorter representations of numbers (larger base) vs. say binary with its long bit strings.